# Good global monitoring service

Tags: web-server, monitoring, website

Is there a monitoring service to monitor my website from different locations on the globe? Like website performance and availability monitoring?

One goal would be to find routing problems and performance bottlenecks.

Note: paid services are fine, too! Important is, that one service offers different locations in one package.

Answer (score 2):

http://www.serverdensity.com

very good and competitive prices.

Answer (score 1):

There are literally tons of these:
Most however are paid services -

check out http://www.freesitestatus.com/ interestingly enough they are the folks behind many of the resellers on the web.

There is also pingdom  -

Hope that helps you get started

As of bottlenecks and such - that might be a different kind of test - called load testing.
If you are on shared hosting - I suggest asking your provider if it is agains their TOS or AUP prior to kicking a test in gear.

Answer (score 1):

[PINGDOM](http://pingdom.com/) maybe?

Answer (score 1):

We use http://www.watchmouse.com/en/ where I work with good results. They monitor from 30 odd locations and provide reports based on location etc. They also offer tools to do traceroutes and various other checks from any of their locations. 
My only complaint would be their pricing, if you need lots of checks it can get a bit pricey, but you do get a really good service.

Answer (score 1):

Happy AlertFox user here... their strong point is [web transaction monitoring](http://wiki.alertfox.com/Transaction_Monitoring) which is a very (*very*) good way of finding performance bottlenecks in complex web applications. Especially those nasty issues that show only "randomly" and do not show up in a local test e. g. with YSlow or Google Page Speed.

They offer real browser monitoring with IE and Firefox, from US, EU and Asian locations.

Answer (score 0):

I have been using [SiteUpTime](http://siteuptime.com/) for quite a few years now and they have never let me down. It's very cost effective, $50/year I think. Extra if you want SMS credits to alert you via SMS (which for me is handy as one of the servers I'm monitoring is responsible for sending email). The only downside is they have only 4 monitoring stations, all of which are located in the USA (I believe). Another service I have looked in to was [uptrends](http://www.uptrends.com/). They offer much more in terms of global monitoring stations. The downside is they are slightly more expensive. However, if it's production equipment that you're monitoring then it may be a small price to pay.

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

We have used www.AlertSite.com for several years and have been very happy. They have sites all over the world.

Answer (score 0):

Just another that I use beyond my Nagios tests:

http://www.websitepulse.com/